# android gradle base project how to use provided scope

Tags: android, build, gradle

I have got project which is part of multiprojects. In subproject I'm using another subproject as library anyway this subproject is already installed on devices as another app. I need add dependency just for development and compile my subproject into apk but I want exclude lib subproject from final app. I was change dependency to provided but gradle always add lib subproject into apk. Is any way how to exclude it from apk and have it just for compilation and development phase?

Answer (score 1):

If your project depends on the lib subproject for compilation, you need to have the apklib in your main project.

However,if you are looking for the other app to be present when the user installs your app (considering you have the author's permission,if you are not the author) you could use PackageManager to check for the presence of the package name of that apk on the device(you cannot directly install the other app, only launch the activity that actually can install it).